# Excel VBA Find function - differentiate multiple results

Tags: excel, vba, function, find

I have a Workbook with two Worksheets. On one worksheet, I have a column of comma separated values as text (electronic component references). E.g. `C1 = "R1, R2, R3, ..., R125" ; C2 = "C1, C2, C3, ..." ; C3 = "TR1, TR2, TR3, ..." ; C4 = "IC1, IC2, IC3 ..."`

I have created the code below to search **column C** on **Sheet2** for a specific value (E.g. "R1"), and when it finds that value, get the part number from another column in same row. E.g. if it finds `R1` in cell `C12`, it will return the part number from cell `D12.`

The code I've written below is working perfectly when **column C** contains only a unique list of comma separated values, but I'm having problems when there are duplicates. E.g. for the example above if `R1` is in cell `C1`, and `TR1` is in cell `C3`, then when I try to find `R1` sometimes it only finds it in Cell `C3`, so returns the incorrect part number for `TR1` instead of `R1`. I have the same problem with `Cxx` and `ICxx` references.

Somehow I need to modify the code so that if I am searching for only `R1` and it is found in a particular cell, then I need to check if the `R1` sub-string has a "T" immediately in front of it ("TR1"), and if so, keep searching.

I may also need to check if the found `R1` has a comma immediately after it (i.e. "R1,"), so that I also don't get problems with e.g. `R1` in one cell, and `R11` in another cell with a different part number.

I don't really have a clue how to modify my code to go about this? Do I need to convert each cell where positive match is found into a string, and then do some kind of sub-string - within - string search?

```
Private Sub Pop_Rel_Click()

    Dim W1 As Workbook
    Set W1 = ActiveWorkbook       
    
    W1.Sheets("Sheet 1").Select
                
    'Select All non-empty cells in Column B (Ref-des) Row 11 onwards...
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("B11:B10000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Select
                                                       
    'Loop through ref-des selection...
    
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim selectedRange As Range
    Dim foundItem As Range
    Set selectedRange = Application.Selection

    For Each cel In selectedRange.Cells
        '...search for corresponding part number from sheet 2
        
        Set foundItem = W1.Sheets("Sheet 2").Range("C11:C1000").Find(What:=cel.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        
        If foundItem Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print cel.Address, cel.Value, "NOT FOUND"
        Else
            'find P/N from sheet 2...
            '...and insert into column C of sheet 1
            cel.Offset(0, 1) = foundItem.Offset(0, -1).Value
             
            Debug.Print cel.Address, cel.Value, foundItem.Address, foundItem.Offset(0, -1).Value, foundItem.Offset(0, 1).Value, foundItem.Offset(0, 2).Value
        End If

        'Debug.Print cel.Address, cel.Value,
    Next cel
                    
    'End loop
        
    MsgBox ("Populated in Worksheet 1:" & Chr(10) & "1. Part Numbers")

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you searching column C or B, your code shows `Range("C11:C1000").Find` ?

Comment: Hi, yes sorry, you are right, I am parsing through all non-blank values in Column B of Sheet 1, and for each value, searching (using find function) column C of sheet 2 for matches. And there are some title/header in rows 1-10, so it only starts at C11. I've edited my question, so hopefully it matches the code a bit better now. Thanks.

Comment: You are only using the first found item, is that OK ?

Comment: If your problem is that you want to find "R1" exactly in a cell with nothing else then change to `LookAt:=xlwhole`. If you need to find more than one result use `FindNext` and loop.

Comment: You are returning the value from Col B not D `cel.Offset(0, 1)=foundItem.Offset(0, -1).Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find a match `Split` the string by comma into an array and check each element of the array for an exact match. If no match is found continue search with `FindNext`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Pop_Rel_Click()
    
    Const HDR = 10 ' 10 rows header
    Dim Wb As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
   
    Dim cel As Range, rngB As Range, rngSearch As Range, rngFound As Range
    Dim ar As Variant, s As String
    Dim i As Long, iLastRow As Long
    Dim sFirstFind As String, bMatch As Boolean

    Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = Wb.Sheets("Sheet 1")
    Set ws2 = Wb.Sheets("Sheet 2")
                    
    'Select All non-empty cells in Column B (Ref-des) Row 11 onwards...
    iLastRow = ws1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngB = ws1.Range("B" & HDR & ":B" & iLastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
   
    iLastRow = ws2.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngSearch = ws2.Range("C" & HDR & ":C" & iLastRow)

    For Each cel In rngB
        
        '...search for corresponding part number from sheet 2
        Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:=cel.Value, _
           LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
           SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
           SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
           MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        
        bMatch = False
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
               
            ' split string by comma into array
            bMatch = False
            sFirstFind = rngFound.Address
            
            Do
                ar = Split(rngFound.Value, ",")
                For i = 0 To UBound(ar)
                    If Trim(ar(i)) = cel Then
                     ' copy
                        cel.Offset(0, 1) = rngFound.Offset(0, 1).Value
                        bMatch = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                Set rngFound = rngSearch.FindNext(rngFound)

            Loop While Not rngFound Is Nothing And bMatch = False _
                       And rngFound.Address <> sFirstFind
        End If
        ' no match
        If bMatch = False Then
            cel.Offset(0, 1) = "not found"
            Debug.Print "NOT FOUND", cel.Address, cel.Value
        End If

    Next cel
    MsgBox ("Populated in Worksheet 1:" & Chr(10) & "1. Part Numbers")
    
End Sub
```